# JavaScript Frameworks similar to Cappuccino

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Can you please point out the JavaScript frameworks that are just like Cappuccino and can be used to build Desktop like applications. I am aware of Closure which is something same as this one. But still can you list some frameworks that would be great enough so as to build a desktop application with ease ? And if it is free and open source then its a +1.

Answer (score 1):

try Sencha

http://www.sencha.com/

Sample Desktop App

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/desktop/desktop.html

It was ExtJS before

Comment: But I have to buy them. Arent there any free and OpenSource Frameworks. I really dont want to spend :(

Comment: I know an opensource version is available but that is for opensource projects only!